# My JS Program doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys, I am really new in JavaScript, and I wrote a really easy program. But unfortunately it isn't working .. 
 **I want it do the operations and display the result into the div with the id "result", Please help.**  
Just ignore this text, I am writing it because I couldn't upload my question otherwise ..

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Calculation Exercise.
    </title>
    <script>
        function adding(){
            num1 = document.getElementById("FirstNumber").value;
            num2 = document.getElementById("SecondNumber").value;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 + num2;
            }
        function subtracting(){
            num1 = document.getElementById("FirstNumber").value;
            num2 = document.getElementById("SecondNumber").value;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
            }
        function multiply(){
            num1 = document.getElementById("FirstNumber").value;
            num2 = document.getElementById("SecondNumber").value;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
            }
        function devide(){
            num1 = document.getElementById("FirstNumber").value;
            num2 = document.getElementById("SecondNumber").value;
            document.getElementById("result"}.innerHTML = num1 / num2;
            }
    </script>
    <style>
        body{
            margin:0; padding:0;}
        h2{
            background-color:yellow; margin-bottom:170; text-align:center;}
        #form1{
            padding-left:760px;}
        #result{
            color:green;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>
            Calculation Exercise.
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="form1">
        <form>
            1st Number : <input type="text" id="FirstNumber" /> <br> 
            2nd Number : <input type="text" id="SecondNumber" /> <br>
            <input type="button" onClick="adding()" value="adding" /> 
            <input type="button" onClick="subtracting()" value="subtracting" />
            <input type="button" onClick="multiply()" value="multiply" />
            <input type="button" onClick="devide()" value="devide" />
        </form>
        The result is :
            <span id="result"> </span>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two syntax errors:

- The last line of your `devide()` function has a `}` instead of `)` next to the selector for ID `result`.
- The math operation in your `subtracting()` function is currently `*` for multiplication but should be `-`.

Fixed version below! Also, FYI, the word is spelled "divide" (not "devide").

```js
function adding() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("FirstNumber").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("SecondNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 + num2;
}

function subtracting() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("FirstNumber").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("SecondNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 - num2;
}

function multiply() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("FirstNumber").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("SecondNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
}

function devide() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("FirstNumber").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("SecondNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 / num2;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 170;
  text-align: center;
}

#result {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>
    Calculation Exercise.
  </h2>
</div>
<div id="form1">
  <form>
    1st Number : <input type="text" id="FirstNumber" /> <br> 2nd Number : <input type="text" id="SecondNumber" /> <br>
    <input type="button" onClick="adding()" value="adding" />
    <input type="button" onClick="subtracting()" value="subtracting" />
    <input type="button" onClick="multiply()" value="multiply" />
    <input type="button" onClick="devide()" value="devide" />
  </form>
  The result is :
  <span id="result"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you mate, I don't use to program in my desktop because I have a really old screen with an awful resolution so I can't notice some of my glaring errors, next time I will make sure to program in my laptop, Thank you !!

Comment: Remember to `parseFloat` and `toFixed` those nums. They're strings at the moment.